# How to query readonly replica in Always On cluster

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, distributed-transactions

We have an Always On "cluster" that consists of 2 servers (there will be more), so one is **PRIMARY** and other(s) is(are) **SECONDARY**. The idea was to dedicate SECONDARY as a readonly replica, so it would be a somewhat search-server.

I do know how to set ConnectionString in the C# so it will use SECONDARY replica - just add `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`.

But I don't understand how to address the SECONDARY from stored procedure if I'm using distributed query. Is there a way to set some parameters to the query (like WITH statements or something), so query would use only replica and not the PRIMARY node?

The thing is, obviously from the start *server1* is PRIMARY and *server2* is SECONDARY, but when *server1* fails then *server2* is PRIMARY and *server1* will be SECONDARY after it get fixed. So I cannot just use the static *server2*'s name.

So far I've managed to get current replica's server name as a variable and use it in EXEC:

```sql
-- find first available replica
DECLARE @replicaServer nvarchar(50)

SELECT TOP 1
    @replicaServer = RCS.replica_server_name
FROM
    sys.availability_groups_cluster AS AGC
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states AS RCS
          ON RCS.group_id = AGC.group_id
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS ARS
          ON ARS.replica_id = RCS.replica_id
    INNER JOIN sys.availability_group_listeners AS AGL
          ON AGL.group_id = ARS.group_id
WHERE ARS.role_desc = 'SECONDARY'
      AND connected_state = 1

-- and query it
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @replicaServer + '].[somebase].[someschema].[sometable]'
EXEC (@cmd)
```

But that's a shame, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some help and hints (especially thanks to *Andriy M*) I've managed to understand what I actually want and how to do it. This article from Microsoft helped as well: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403414.aspx

First I had to create a **read only listener**. And then at the other server add linked server like this (borrowed from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585304):

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server     = N'cluster-readonly', -- just a name
    @srvproduct = N'SQL', -- anything except 'SQL Server'
    @provider   = N'SQLNCLI11',
    @datasrc    = N'ClusterListener', -- name of the readonly listener
    @provstr    = N'ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly',
    @catalog    = N'AnyActualDataBase' -- system database like 'master' is no good
GO
```

How do I check, where am I:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([cluster-readonly], 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME')
```

Here's some trick - if I don't specify `@catalog`, then connection will be to the PRIMARY node for some reasons.

Comment: Thanks! You've saved me a lot of time searching for this.

Comment: @retif the reason you must specify appropriate database is that it must check if target database participates in Availability Group before routing kicks in.

> An alternative to this would be the login used in the connection has the database configured as its default database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server Management Studio supports adding items to the connection string when connecting to a server through the "Connect to Server" dialog box:

[image]

Adding `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;` to the 'Additional Connection Parameters' box (as shown in the above image) should accomplish what you need.

You may also need to add `Database='YourDatabase';` if your default database is not part of an Availability Group.  If you don't add the `Database='YourDatabase';` part, you may still connect to the primary host, since the default master database is not part of your Availability Group.

Comment: Well, and what if I'm connected to the any other server, not in a cluster, and I'm in stored procedure wanting to SELECT some table from the SECONDARY replica of cluster? Like <code>SELECT * FROM [CLUSTERname].[somebase].[someschema].[sometable]</code>. Is there a way to set that I want to query SECONDARY server for readonly purpose?